# How to change the servlet mapping in JoinFaces?

Tags: spring-boot, joinfaces

The default servlet mapping in JoinFaces seems to be `*.jsf`.

How may I change it to a different mapping? I could not find a setting in Spring Boots application config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from JoinFaces 3.1.0, it is possible to configure servlet mapping. See [details.](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces/issues/356)